# How to use CASE in SQL to set multiple WHERE conditions?

Tags: sql, sql-server

The `Case` is returning syntax error while trying to set more than one condition to the query. The `Store Procedure` takes a param `@isAdmin` which I use later to select different data based on User Type.

Below is the query of the Store Procedure

```
SELECT orU.userName as userOrder,orf.OrderID
FROM App.orderF orf
Inner Join app.Users orU
On orf.LastUpdatedBy = orU.UserID
   
Where
   -- ADDING THE CASE HERE
    Case @isAdmn
        WHEN 0 THEN LastUpdatedBy = @UserID AND SiteDataID=@SiteDataID 
        WHEN 1 THEN SiteDataID=@SiteDataID

-- ORDER BY IS NOT IN SIDE THE CASE
ORDER BY LastUpdatedDate DESC
```

The above query says there is an error near `=`

[image]

EDIT: Actual Query

```
SELECT orU.userName as userOrder,orf.OrderID, orf.OrderNumber, orf.TotalAmount, Convert(VARCHAR,orf.OrderDate,106) as OrderDate, orf.OrderStatus,orf.LastUpdatedBy as UserID
        FROM App.OrderFinal orf
        Inner Join app.Users orU
        On orf.LastUpdatedBy = orU.UserID
         
        Where
        Case @isAdmn
        WHEN 0 THEN LastUpdatedBy = @UserID AND SiteDataID=@SiteDataID 
        WHEN 1 THEN SiteDataID=@SiteDataID 

        ORDER BY LastUpdatedDate DESC
```

Comment: You need a space after `--` to make a comment. `--Where` is missing the space.

Comment: The query in the text is not the same as the query in the screenshot. Please copy and paste the actual query.

Comment: Are you sure you're using MySQL? That error message doesn't look like a MySQL message. It looks like SQL-Server.

Comment: @Barmar pasted the actual query, it is SQL server, but added MySql tag since both have the `Case`

Comment: Yes, they both have CASE, but they have lots of other differences, which could be relevant (they don't happen to be relevant in this case, though).

Comment: @Barmar: They *are* relevant here, because MySQL allows the `CASE` expression to result in a boolean value and SQL Server doesn't :-)

Comment: `where SiteDataID = @SiteDataID and (@isAdmn = 1 or LastUpdatedBy = @UserID)`

Comment: Why does everyone automatically jump to the assumption they need a case expression? Aren't logical operators taught any more?

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the `END` for the `CASE` expression:

```
WHERE
  CASE @isAdmn
    WHEN 0 THEN LastUpdatedBy = @UserID AND SiteDataID = @SiteDataID 
    WHEN 1 THEN SiteDataID = @SiteDataID
  END
```

---

**Update:** You have changed your tags from MySQL to SQL Server. SQL Server SQL doesn't have a boolean data type, so the `CASE` expression result cannot be a boolean. `SiteDataID = @SiteDataID` is a boolean value (true or false), and so is `LastUpdatedBy = @UserID AND SiteDataID = @SiteDataID`. This does not work in SQL Server.

---

But usually you would not have a `CASE` expression in `WHERE` anyhow, because with `CASE` you create a boolean expression check, which the `WHERE` clause already is:

```
WHERE SiteDataID = @SiteDataID AND (@isAdmn = 1 OR LastUpdatedBy = @UserID)
```

Comment: FYI it was me who changed the tag, as he admitted in the comments that he used the wrong tag, and the error message is a SQL-Server error.

Comment: @Barmar: Yes, I read that. Thank you for getting this information for us. It was vital to the reason for the error.

Comment: Yes, it explains why the error is near `=`.

Comment: @Dale K: That's true. Thank you. This escaped me when I updated my answer to adjust it for SQL Server. I've updated my answer once more.

Answer (score 1):

CASE does not control which lines of code run in this context. It returns a value. You need to use that value. You also need an END on it.

```
SELECT orU.userName as userOrder,orf.OrderID, orf.OrderNumber, orf.TotalAmount, Convert(VARCHAR,orf.OrderDate,106) as OrderDate, orf.OrderStatus,orf.LastUpdatedBy as UserID
        FROM App.OrderFinal orf
        Inner Join app.Users orU
        On orf.LastUpdatedBy = orU.UserID
         
        WHERE
            LastUpdatedBy = 
                CASE @isAdmn
                    WHEN 0 THEN @UserID
                    WHEN 1 THEN LastUpdatedBy 
                END
            AND SiteDataID = @SiteDataID
        ORDER BY LastUpdatedDate DESC
```

Currently, your cases are doing the same thing, but that is what your code says and I'm sure not what your intent is. At any rate, this is how you use CASE in a WHERE clause.

**Update:** Your various screenshots and code aren't doing the same thing and I can't tell what your actual desired outcome is.

**Update2:** Code updated to reflect the clarified requirement.

Comment: I need to take out `LastUpdatedBy` when `@isAdmn` is `1`. I updated the actual query in the question if you could take a look again. I am not able to apply the logic on the way you added the `Case`

Comment: You're returning the same values in both `WHEN` clauses, so what's the point of the `CASE`?

Comment: @Barmar: Hence my note about his sample doing the same thing in both cases.

Comment: But it's not. In one case it tests `LastUpdatedBy`, in the other case it doesn't.

Comment: You could change your first `CASE` to use `WHEN 1 THEN LastUpdatedBy` to be equivalent.

Comment: @Barmar: Yes, I'm doing that now. If you look at his question, you'll see that the second "actual query" does the same thing in both cases, as opposed to the first, which does not.

Comment: yeah, I complained at the very beginning that the screenshot isn't the same as the text queries.

Comment: @Barmar: And then he added a third version that does not match either of the first two. :)